# How can I switch axes of array?

Tags: numpy

I have numpy.ndarray like this:

```
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 2,  6,  8,  8, 12, 15, 20, 12,  7,  7,  3]], dtype=int64)
```

I want to switch axes so it looks like this:

```
[[2, 2],
 [3, 6],
 [4, 8],
 ....
 ....
 [11, 7],
 [12, 3]]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transpose the array with `array.T`. See [the documentation for `np.ndarray.T`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html).

```py
>>> x = np.array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
...        [ 2,  6,  8,  8, 12, 15, 20, 12,  7,  7,  3]])
>>> x
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 2,  6,  8,  8, 12, 15, 20, 12,  7,  7,  3]])
>>> x.T
array([[ 2,  2],
       [ 3,  6],
       [ 4,  8],
       [ 5,  8],
       [ 6, 12],
       [ 7, 15],
       [ 8, 20],
       [ 9, 12],
       [10,  7],
       [11,  7],
       [12,  3]])
>>>
```